# High Speed Python Web Scraper Optimised

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, cython

I needed a lot of data for a tensorflow project so I made a web scraper to get all of the text and links off of websites then to repeat the process at all of those links.

I left it on overnight and it did not get much done, so I spent the day optimizing it. I can't find any ways to optimize it more (If anyone knows a way I would like to hear it.) I used it on CNN and now I have a 9 gig text file.

BTW: I used faster_than_requests and selectolax because they are faster then urllib3 and bs4 and you should check them out

```
import cython # helps speed up code
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser #bs4 but faster
import faster_than_requests #urllib but faster
import _pickle as pickle #saving code
from colorama import init #just makes error messages stand out
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style


init() #colorama thing

#cdef is a cython thing, helping speed up code
cdef int i = 0

cdef list urls
cdef list text

cdef set visits #is a set for efficiency 

cdef str mainsite = "https://www.cnn.com" #The main site keeps the scraper 
                     #from straying too far from its original site.
cdef str source

parsing = True

try:
  with open('visits.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    visload = pickle.load(f)
    visits = visload[1]
    i = visload[0]
except Exception as e:
  print(Back.RED + "Error loading Visits: " + str(e))
  visits = set('')
  i = 0

try:
  with open('txt.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    txt = pickle.load(f)
except Exception as e:
  print(Back.RED + "Error loading txt: " + str(e))
  txt = []


try:
  with open('links.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    urls = pickle.load(f)
except Exception as e:
  print(Back.RED + "Error loading urls: " + str(e))
  urls = ["https://www.cnn.com"]

while parsing:

  try:
    if urls[0][0] == "/": #checks to see if it can go 
                          # to the site directly or it needs to add 
                          #the main site to the front
      source = faster_than_requests.get2str(mainsite + urls[0])
      dom = HTMLParser(source)
      print(Back.BLACK + mainsite + urls[0])
    else:
      source = faster_than_requests.get2str(urls[0])
      dom = HTMLParser(source)
      print(Back.BLACK + urls[0])

    for tag in dom.tags('p'):
      txt.append(str(dom.text())) #finds text and saves it

    for tag in dom.tags('a'): 
      attrs = tag.attributes
      if 'href' in attrs:
          urls.append(attrs['href']) #finds links and saves them
  except:
    print(Back.RED + f"Error: {urls[0]}") # it will through up an error 
                                          # if it tries to go to a sub-page
                                          # of another site, but this is
                                          # an intended feature 

  visits.add(urls[0])
  #visits keeps track of visites web pages 

  i = i + 1
  clean = True

  #clean make shure that it does not repeat a webpage.
  while clean:
    if urls[0] in visits:
      del(urls[0])
    else:
      clean = False

  print(Back.BLACK + f"urls:{len(urls)}, i:{i}, text lang:{len(txt)}")

  if i % 10000 == 0:
    #Save every 10000 webpages
    with open('txt.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(txt, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    with open('links.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(urls, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    with open('visits.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump([i, visits], f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


  if 0 == len(urls):
    parsing = False
    print(txt)
    with open('txt.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(txt, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    with open('links.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(urls, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    with open('visits.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump([i, visits], f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: Is there a good alternative to pickle that A- does not take three hours to save huge files, and B- compacts files better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want absolute performance

1. You could avoid printing anything at all. Since that can be slow in some cases. If you absolutly need to know at least what happened you could try flushing at the end of the process.
2. I know with python is delicated, but you could try visiting multiple pages at the same time? Threads or the equivalent in python

Comment: I was wondering, if print was slowing it down. I might only do it when the file saves.